# Dropzone stops on the progress bar

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

This will be hard to explain, because I have no live demo. I use a simple dropzone.

HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost/upload.php" class="dropzone" method="post" id="upload-widget"></form>
```

JavaScript:

```
Dropzone.options.uploadWidget = {
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    init: function() {
        this.on('success', function() {
            alert('OK);
        });
    }
};
```

upload.php file:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
        //insert file information into db table
    }
}
```

When I pick or drop a file, it will upload, but stops at the progress:

[image]

I have no idea, why. When I upload any file, file appear in the /uploads/ folder, but seems like dropzone.js doesn't react on complete. Do I need to print some data? I used this website as tutorial http://www.codexworld.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-using-dropzone-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm using this PHP debugger: https://github.com/JosephLenton/PHP-Error which for some unknown reasons disabled receiving XHTTP responses (funny that my website is almost whole in ajax and I haven't noticed any error). Anyway, I can't use dropzone.js with this debugger. I can live with that (also it is turned off when it will go to production).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the `success` event like that :

```
Dropzone.options.uploadWidget = {
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    success: function(file, res) {
        console.log('Upload success.');
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(file, res) {
        console.log('Upload error.');
        console.log(res);
    }
};
```

Comment: There is no problem with event. There is problem that progress bar never ends. So it will never emit events like `succes complete error...`. Anyway tried and not working.

Comment: Did you get any error messages in your console ? And when the upload is complete, you don't get the 'Success' message ?